# Knockout: Can't push to observableArray

Tags: html, knockout.js

I've recently started using KnockOut, so I'm very new to this. 
I have completed every tutorial on their site, yet can't get this specific thing to work.

I have to arrays, on the left being all the items, on the right being the items you've selected.

Once you click on the item (left table), it should `.push` to the right table

**ViewModel**:

```
var orderedItemsTable = $("form.orderedDataWithoutBatch")

var viewModel = {
    //right side
    orderedItems: ko.observableArray(),

    //Left side
    items: ko.observableArray(),
    sortColumn: ko.observable(),
    total: ko.observable(),
}

request.done(function (data) {
     item.addItem = function () {
                alert("item clicked, materiaal id: " + this.MateriaalId);//works
                alert(this.MateriaalDescription);//works
                viewModel.orderedItems.push(this);//doesn't 'work'
        }

            viewModel.items.push(item);//unrelated to this context
     }
```

I'm assuming it's either in this code here, or I'm not showing it correctly in my html (because I'm not getting any console errors)

**HTML** (right side)

```
<form id="OrderedItemsWithoutBatch" class="orderedDataWithoutBatch">
<table class="orderFormArticlesTable" style="width: 47%;float: right; font-size: 9pt;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalSku"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalDescription"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalId"><!-- Quantity--> </td>
            <!--<td><input class="orderedQty" style="max-width: 15%" value="1" />[pieces]</td>-->
            <td><a href="#">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.push(item)` to make sure it isn't a `this` context related problem? Also: shouldn't the done's callback parameter be named `item`?

Comment: @user3297291 Yes, I've tried both. It doens't really matter, both 'item' and 'this' carry the same data. 

I don't know why I've called 'this', this either.. However, I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue  then... What's different between your code and this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/90u0wnuL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood you right, but I'd solve your task this way:

```js
var orderedItemsTable = $("form.orderedDataWithoutBatch")

var viewModel = {
    //right side
    orderedItems: ko.observableArray(),

    //Left side
    items: ko.observableArray(),
    sortColumn: ko.observable(),
    total: ko.observable(),
}

function proscessRequest(item) {
     item.addItem = function () {
          //alert("item clicked, materiaal id: " + this.MateriaalId);//works
          //alert(item.MateriaalDescription);//works
          viewModel.orderedItems.push(this);//doesn't 'work'
     }

     viewModel.items.push(item);//unrelated to this context
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

proscessRequest({MateriaalSku: "M1", MateriaalDescription: "D1", MateriaalId: "1"});
proscessRequest({MateriaalSku: "M2", MateriaalDescription: "D2", MateriaalId: "2"});
proscessRequest({MateriaalSku: "M3", MateriaalDescription: "D3", MateriaalId: "3"});
proscessRequest({MateriaalSku: "M4", MateriaalDescription: "D4", MateriaalId: "4"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="OrderedItemsWithoutBatch" class="orderedDataWithoutBatch">
  <div>Alavilable items:</div>
<div>
  <table class="orderFormArticlesTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalSku"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalDescription"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalId"><!-- Quantity--> </td>
            <td><div data-bind="click: addItem">Add</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

  <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div>Ordered items:</div>
    <table class="orderFormArticlesTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalSku"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalDescription"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalId"><!-- Quantity--> </td>
            <td><div data-bind="click: function() { $parent.orderedItems.remove($data); }">Remove</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

#### Note

I've mocked request with "proscessRequest" function called after bindings have been applied.

Comment: I've made a few minor changes and it finally works. Thank you very much. I've set this scrum for 8 hours, I'm at hour 37 now. x)